# Error "Use SSL (https) when passing an access_token" after FB.login()

Tags: facebook, ssl, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I've got a strange Javascript issue with FB.login(). Actually I want to use the FB.login() method to check if a user gave some extended permission, or better, to get an FB dialog which prompts the user to give the permission if he hasn't.

The JS code I use:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log(authResponse);
    }
}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
```

When this is executed, Facebook shows an overlay saying "Use SSL (https) when passing an access_token".

[Here's a Screenshot](http://seck.sc-dev2.de/fb-ssl-error.png).

I googled this message and didn't get a single result ([seriously](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22Use%20SSL%20%28https%29%20when%20passing%20an%20access_token%22)).

This only seems to appear for users with the "new" login dialog (the one which first asks the user to access public profile and friends list and after that, in a new dialog, which can be skipped, it asks for extended permissions). It works as it should for a user who still has the old login dialog.

The app is sandboxed, I'm browsing FB without SSL. I can't switch to SSL because it isn't supported by the server I'm developing on. I can't change that and it also would not really be a solution for this problem. And: I never had trouble because of non-SSL app hosting. This is the first time I experience FB complaining in that manner about missing SSL.

I also made sure that FB's all.js is fetched from an https:// url, which unfortunately didn't change anything.

Ideas, anyone? Because of 0 google results, I'm afraid it's not really a known problem or it's so stupid nobody did ever have to write about it... :D

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

there's a bug report for this, which is assigned with high prio (at the moment of writing this answer): have a look here:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/416916061737216?browse=search_515d67216f3885909623600